# How to create bows and arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to kill!

Comment: Here's the list of all recipes, by the way: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Crafting

Comment: @JavadocMD I was looking for that

Comment: What a "nice" question body!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bow

You'll need sticks from wood, string from spiders, flint from gravel, and feathers from chickens or zombies.

Comment: You can get arrows from killing skeletons too.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you're just looking for something to help you kill things, a sword would work as well.

Even a wooden sword does as much damage as an arrow (and is much easier to make, as you don't need to kill spiders for their string without a weapon!)

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword

Comment: I find it harder to skill skeletons with a sword than with a bow, though.